# Sorting Column with alphanumeric values in datatable

Tags: sorting, datatable

I have a column with values Prefixed with 'C' like `C72, C4, C54, C39`, When I sort this in desc order, It becomes,

```
C72, C54, C4, C39
```

But I wan't it to be

```
C72, C54, C39, C4
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  Does every value in the column have the format `C###`, i.e. a single letter `C` followed by any number of digits?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes Every values are prefixed with `C`

Comment: I've posted an answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MSSQL SERVER, You can achieve it by using `PATINDEX` & `CAST` OR `CONVERT`. Retrieve only the Numeric part from each values as Substring using PATINDEX and cast the retrieved value to `INT` using `CAST` and use `Order By`

```
Select *  
From 
    Tablename 
ORDER BY 
    CAST(substring([colname],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[colname]),len([colname])) AS INT) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link if you are using SQL Server..
http://www.essentialsql.com/use-sql-server-to-sort-alphanumeric-values/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by the number proceeding the letter `C` in descending order, then you can just substring off the text of the number and cast to an integer:

```
SELECT col
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 2, LEN(col) - 1) AS INT) DESC
```

This answer assumes that every value in the column is prefixed by a letter `C`.

Comment: Thank you so much, But the problem is I got data as i expected while retrieving through query, But In datatable same problem occurred .

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: I want to implement the same sorting in datatable, It randomize my data, Won't be useful however I sort it while retrieving through query.

Comment: There is no internal order in your database.  The only order which exists is what you impose at the time when you query.

Comment: Yah, I got that... I used the query and data ordered as I expected, Then I used datatable to show the data, But It's again ordered randomly as per it's default setting...

Comment: The "default," and only option, is random ordering internally.

Comment: Can I customize the sorting of data in datatable as you did in query ?

Comment: I think the closest thing to what you want would be to create an _index_ on the column in question.  But SQL Server doesn't support function indices AFAIK, so this cannot even be done in SQL Server.